# Sed parsing >50 MB file with over 50k lines failing with no error

Tags: regex, sed

I'm parsing a description file (given in question) with this magic sed

> sudo sed -nE 's/(^[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}) .*
>   http://(.*?)\s+.*$/!\1 \2/p'

Even when I copy sample lines from orginial files and put in temp file it works but on complete file its failing. I tried debugging using `!` switch but too doesn't work it return no unsuccessful matches. Where I go with this?

**Background**
I have a case, a file which I need to `post-process`. The sample format is given below:-

```
bigspeedpro.com Intel::DOMAIN   from http://malc0de.com/bl/BOOT via intel.criticalstack.com     F
1.1.1.1 Intel::DOMAIN   from http://abcd.com/bl/BOOT via intel.criticalstack.com     F
```

Expected output is :--

```
1.1.1.1 abcd
```

Parsing is as:-

- Anything which doesn't start with IP address delete that line
- If start with IP address do

  - delete Intel::DOMAIN
  - between  `from`  to  `F` replace it based upon following strings occurrences
  - e.g malc0de or abcd

**PART 2**

I want only 
12.2.2.2  Intel::DOMAIN   from `http://hosts-file.net/fsa.txt` via intel.criticalstack.com  F

`http://hosts-file.net/fsa.txt`

I use

> sudo sed -nE 's/(^[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}) .*
>   http://(.*)\s+?$/ \1 \2/p'

Its giving me

> 12.2.2.2 hosts-file.net/fsa.txt via intel.criticalstack.com

I don't want this?

**solved part 2**

> silkman@Silky-flows:~/tmp$ sudo sed -nE
>   's/(^[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}) .*
>   http://(.*?)\s+[v][i][a].*$/ \1 \2/p'

**update**

> ```
> 1.1.1.1 www.abc.com
> 1.1.2.2 def.com
> 2.2.2.2 mnx.dbc.net
> ```

However, I want second column after ip address to be shortened to a string of my own choice for e.g in second column I only accept

> abc
>   def
>   mnx

Once, its found just replace entire string as

```
1.1.1.1 abc
1.1.2.2 def
2.2.2.2 mnx
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Gowtham no error the output is redirected to file with zero contents.

Comment: @Cyrus is it better now?

Comment: Not sure if this will fix the issue, but I will ask if you see anything to worry about with this: `sed -nE 's/http:///\1\2/p'`?

Comment: @ChronoKitsune thats for part 2? right

Comment: @asad Let me make it even simpler: `s/x///\1\2/p`. Did you notice that it has too many `/` characters? If you're using `/` as a delimiter, then you need to escape its literal use as `\/`.

Comment: you don't specify a file to work on. And could you send proper input and desired output? It's pretty hard to understand your question.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune why you deleted your answer??

Comment: I'm still confused , `s/x///\1\2/p` where should I place it?

Comment: @asad You don't place it anywhere. I was illustrating a point: `s/x///\1/p` has too many `/` characters. And I deleted my answer because the Perl version is better and works for you.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune yeah I understand the escaping part, I have revised the one liner as you can see on thread. Thanks for highlighting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about some perl code:

```
perl -ne 's/Intel::DOMAIN.*from http:\/\/(.+?)\..*/\1/; m/^(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}/ and print'
```

It first removes unwanted text and prints the line only if it begins with something that looks like an IP address. If you cannot use perl code, it might be possible to "port" this to sed.

Comment: Great results it parse 80% of the lines, but I don't want "Intel::ADDR" and stuff between "from" and "via" the long URI I WANT TO keep

Comment: Can you post a sample input line and expected output for the remaining 20%?

Comment: `perl -ne 's/Intel::[a-zA-Z]+.*from http:\/\/(.+?)\..*/\1/; m/^(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\s+/ and print'` I revised a bit now the 20% is just wrong syntax which i don't want to keep. Where I'm stuck is cleaning part I capture `from` and `via` string. I want to replace that 'string' what my own (already known). Kindly see update.

Comment: @asad I don't understand. I believe an example input and expected output would make it more clear.

Comment: I want to put /32 prefix at end of IP address I cannot do using this syntax `perl -ne 's/Intel::[a-zA-Z]+.*from http:\/\/(.+?)\/..*/\1/; m/^(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\s+/\/32 and print`